# combining two RDDs by values in scala spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have two RDDs.

rdd1 = (string, integer)

```
(a, 10)
(b, 15)
(c, 20)
(d, 20)
(e, 13)
```

rdd2 = (string, string)

```
(1, a)
(2, b)
(3, e)
```

When some of rdd2's values are the same with rdd1's keys, how can I merge them like below? Is it possible?

```
(1, 10)
(2, 15)
(3, 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2.map(_.swap)).values
```

Comment: It's not working. It says 'Cannot resolve symbol join'.. Do you know why?

Comment: Probably `rdd1` is not RDD.

Comment: oh, yeah right! I think it's not RDD but has the same format like above. Then do you have any other suggestions to merge them?

Comment: Make it into an RDD? (`sc.parallelize`)